# How do I change the order of the y-axis in ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a `geom_density_ridges_gradient()` graph in R, and want to order the y-axis in chronological order of release (a separate variable in my dataframe). How can I edit my `ggplot()` command to make this happen? Here is what I currently have, and attached is the output. Or, for simplicity sake, how can I manually order the y-axis categories?

```
ggplot(ts, aes(x = danceability, y = album_name)) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(scale = .9) +
  theme_light() +
  labs(title = "Danceability by Albums",
       x = "Danceability",
       y = "Album Name")
```

[Plot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugLnT.png)

Comment: Can you try `y=reorder(y, release_date)`, where `release_date` is the variable in `ts` by which you want to order y?

Comment: @langtang I just tried this and it did not change the order. Where exactly does this y = reorder(y, release_date) go? I put it as: ```ggplot(ts, aes(x = valence, y = reorder(album_name, album_release_date)))```

Comment: yes, that's right. I actually just tried on a dataset, and it worked to reorder. Can you provide the datasett

Comment: @langtang I got it - I hadn't made the dates into a date type. However, now it has the earliest at the bottom of the y-axis. How can I do it in reverse order so that earliest is at the top? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: you can add decreasing = T. I'll post as an answer

Comment: @langtang decreasing = T did not change the output. Also tried decreasing = F just in case but that also did not work

Comment: must be something with your data structure, which you did not provide. I'll add to the answer in the hope that it helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the column in `ts` by which you would like to order `y` is called `release_date`, you can try `reorder()`, with `decreasing=T`

```
ggplot(ts, aes(x = danceability, y = reorder(album_name, release_date,decreasing=T)) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(scale = .9) +
  theme_light() +
  labs(title = "Danceability by Albums",
       x = "Danceability",
       y = "Album Name")
```

While no data were provided, we can see this in action here:

```
set.seed(123)
data = data.frame(y=rep(letters[1:3],100), x=rnorm(300), o=rep(c(1,3,2),100))

gridExtra::grid.arrange(
  ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_density_ridges_gradient(scale=0.9) + ggtitle("Unordered"),
  ggplot(data, aes(x,reorder(y,o,decreasing=T))) + geom_density_ridges_gradient(scale=0.9) + ggtitle("Ordered")
)
```

[image: yorder_plot]